# Can we get rid of the [issue-tracking] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are 12 questions tagged [`issue-tracking`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking). Most of them are also tagged with something else, usually the actual issue tracking system they are asking about.

Those tagged with only `issue-tracking` seem to be looking for recommendations, so → off-topic.

[The only question where the tag has some merit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48691/how-to-change-labels-in-sourceforge-bug-tracker) is tagged both `issue-tracking` and `sourceforge`, as it is about the SourceForge issue tracker. But I would rather we had a specific tag for that system, like `sourceforge-issue-tracker`.

Since the `issue-tracking` tag does not seem to be able to do anything useful by itself, I'm voting to get rid of it.

Comment: There are no more questions with this tag and it has been cleaned up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would tend to agree. Really the only way it has any utility is as a catch-all for any issue tracking apps that don't have enough questions to support the tag. (Tags on single questions get removed after some time.) But that's a really dubious reason.

I see you've done some clean up. I'll do some as well. If we can get it off of all questions it'll be auto-deleted.